# Problem with date types after excel upload (converting timestamp to datetime)

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I've got data in excel, one sheet has dates as columns, the other - as rows. Using pd.read_excel I get them as dataframes. The type of one (Data1) is datetime.datetime, the other (Data2) is timestamp.

1. How do I prevent this from happening and get uniform types?

I want to do

```
Data1[Data1.index<Data2.columns[-1]]
```

this returns an error

> TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and
> 'Timestamp'

I tried doing

```
datetime(Data2.columns[-1].year,Data2.columns[-1].month,Data2.columns[-1].day)
```

instead of

```
Data2.columns[-1]
```

the error changes to

> TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and
> 'datetime.datetime'

2. I'm lost, how do I get the types to match? What's this datetime.time type out of thin air.

EDIT

this seems to be the crux of the issue:

```
Data1[Data1.index<Data1.index[3]]
```

returns

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and
> 'datetime.datetime'

Data type for Data1.index is datetime.time.

Comment: Both error messages suggest that the type of Data1 is in fact `datetime.time`.

Comment: Curiously, this produces the same error message

Comment: Sorry, I have zero experience with pandas. But to convert between datetimes and timestamp floats, you can do `dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)` and `ts = dt.timestamp()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to compare apples with apples. Either compare full datetime (date and time component) or only one of each. Ex:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

# date and time:
pd.Timestamp('now') >= datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)
# False

# time only:
pd.Timestamp('now').time() >= (datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)).time()
# False

# date only:
pd.Timestamp('now').date() >= (datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)).date()
# True
```

as opposed to e.g.

```
pd.Timestamp('now').time() >= (datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1))
```

...will throw

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and
> 'datetime.datetime'

Comment: Thanks, this was precisely the problem, turns out I had a few datetime.time() in there and was comparing datetime.datetime with datetime.time.